# mysql lib socket vs run socket

Tags: mysql

Why is it that when I use this setting in my my.conf:

```
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid
```

I get lightning fast speeds in http, but as soon as it moved to https I get the "Unable to establish connection to database" error. If I switch it back to my old:

```
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

it's much slower, but https works fine. Nothing shows up in the error log in the first example. I would LOVE to keep the /var/lib socket speeds, but I need https to work on the site.

Comment: This is a going to be a misconfiguration somewhere in your web app.  The location of the socket makes no difference, and has no relationship to http/https.

Comment: It's standard Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If you edit the socket location in my.conf, you have to change it in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf to match (obviously, for Debian based distros.)